# How to pass form <p> data to router function using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to write a page where the user is presented a list of unverified accounts, each of them with their own form element. Each of the form elements has their own "submit" button which sends a `POST` call to `/verify`. The issue I'm having is the `<p>` data in the form is not visible in `/verify`. How do I give the server access to this form data?

This function serves up the data from which we build the verify account page:

```
router.get('/verifyAccounts', function(req, res){
    userData.find({"Verified": false}, function(err, user){
        //console.log(user);
        res.render('listUnverified', {listOf: user});
    });
});
```

This function is the `/verify` function that we are trying to pass the data to:

```
router.post('/verify', function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    var email = req.body.orgEmail;
    console.log(email);
    userData.update({"Email": email}, {$set: {"Verified": true}}, function(err, user) {
        res.redirect('/verifyAccounts');
    });
    //res.redirect('/');
});
```

The code from which the verify account page is built is:

```
<!doctype html>
    <h1>THIS IS A LIST OF UNVERIFIED ORGANIZATION ACCOUNTS</h1>
    {{# each listOf }}
    <form action = "/verify" method="post">
        <p name="orgName">{{ Org }}</p>
        <p name="orgEmail">{{ Email }}</p>
        <p name="orgPassword">{{ Password }}</p>
        <button type="submit">Verify</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    {{/each}}
```

So essentially what I want is for the `/verify` function be able to access fields in the form whose "submit" button was clicked, such as the text in the `orgName` paragraph element. Any idea how I might accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` isn't a form element, it's just a display element.  So essentially you have an empty form.  You want `input` elements to hold the form data.  Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="orgName" value="{{ Org }}" />
```

You can also have both, perhaps using a `<p>` to display the information and a hidden form element to pass it to the server:

```
<p>{{ Org }}</p>
<input type="hidden" name="orgName" value="{{ Org }}" />
```

Note that users can of course change the values of anything they send to the server.